# STM32F4 and AWS Kinesis video stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, stm32

I am developing the smart camera with a STM32F4

Is there any chance I will have issue installing the C++ SDK of Kinesis Video Stream on my hardware ? Knowing that STM32F4 support RTOS mainly

Thanks a lot for your help

(https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-cpp)

Comment: You need to analyse what are this SDK requirements: does it use OS services ? How much RAM or Flash does it need ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should better chance with c producer sdk instead of cpp: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-c. You should first verify whether you can port the dependencies of producer c sdk to your platform. They are curl and openssl. After that porting the producer c sdk should be possible.

Comment: There is a Kinesis Video Streams producer for embedded c now : https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-embedded-c